# How does Google Drive (or other services) capture the Ctrl+F or Command+F input for a custom search box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-drive-api

Is it possible to create a custom "find" box similar to what Google Drive does upon pressing Command+F or Ctrl+F? I'm a complete noob and I'm not sure how to phrase this question better, I'm sorry!

Comment: Welcome to SO - your post is lacking in detail/too broad to get a good answer at the moment, could you provide a bit more detail of where you are trying to achieve this find box - as part of something related to Google Drive, or on your own website for example? More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Very good question but badly asked. +1

Answer (score 3):

They capture the `keydown` event on `document` and prevent the default action from occurring, doing their own thing instead:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which || e.keyCode) == 70) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Search!");
    }
}, false);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which || e.keyCode) == 70) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Search!");
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<p>Click here to focus the snippet's document, then press Ctrl+F</p>
```

The event object the handler receives has a `ctrlKey` property which will have a truthy value if the ctrl key is down. On most browsers, it will also have a `which` property to say which key, but on some it's `keyCode`, so in the above I used the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to use whichever one the browser provided.

Comment: It always amazes me that how much effort and time people spend while answering and earn reputation. You are an excellent example of that. Even if  we remove the `k` from your reputation, you will still have more reputation than that of mine.